# Can't pop up the webpage (python, selenium)

Tags: python, selenium

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k4R0.jpg)

When i run code,
It says 'process finished with exit code 0'

HOWEVER, IT Doesn't pop up the website.

Why? Please help emergency

Comment: Your code editor shows polling.py but your terminal shows main.py. What happens when you run `python polling.py` from the Command Prompt.

Comment: I know this is your first post, but it is not what a post is supposed to be. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to be posting your *actual code* so that we can copy, paste and run it to try to duplicate your problem and perhaps correct it, not an image of it.

Comment: Have you tried opening up a browser and entering `http://emart.ssq.com` in the URL field (if that is what the URL is supposed to be; it's hard to make it out from the image -- see my previous comment). This URL cannot be found, at least when I try it, so what do you experience when you try it and what would you expect when you use Selenium?